# `GLIBC_2.34' not found in chromebook

Tags: glibc, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I've installed megacc on my chromebook, however when I try to run the application this error comes up:

`megacc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by megacc)`

I have version 112.0.5615.134 of ChromeOs

I've tried to update glibc but still doesn't work.